# How to make image clickable if -1 z-index is given to create box-shadow?

Tags: jquery, html, css

My post contain Image with box shadow using Css3. To create box shadow z-index of -1 given to img tag. But problem is that image is not clickable .As href tag is given to image, How can I create my image clickable with keeping Box-shadow too?

My CSS:

```
.postimage {
width:100%;
height:250px;
margin:10px 0px 20px 0px;
z-index:12; box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
}
.postimage img{
position:relative;
z-index:-1;
}
```

My Html:

```
<div class="postimage">
    <a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="images/bg.jpeg" /></a>
</div>
```

Without using -1 z-index image become clickable ,but css3 box shadow doesn't work.

Comment: Items with a z-index of -1 will not be clickable because they are rendered behind anything with a z-index greater than or equal to 0, as well as their backgrounds.

Comment: There are no words to describe `"Is Jquery required?"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.postimage').on('click', function() {
    var newURL = $('a', this).prop('href');
    window.location = newURL ;
});
```

Comment: Thanks roXon! Its nice to get it through jQuery. Now I can implement same using transparent shadow frame  over this image by setting another absolute div having shadow frame as background. And my click event is set over this absolute div.

Answer (score -1):

change `z-index:-1;` to `z-index:1;`

Comment: With z-index:1 there is no box-shadow.

Answer (score -1):

You can make an element transparent to mouse events (so click will go through) by setting

```
pointer-events: none;
```